# Blazor Server - HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

Tags: asp.net, server, blazor

I'm getting this error when publishing my Blazor Server application after adding file uploads.

My project is using .net5

In my startup.cs file I have this code, in which if commented out, causes no errors.  If I comment it out and publish the application works again but obviously file uploads stop working.

```
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Files")),
            RequestPath = "/Files"
        });
        app.UseRouting();
```

Further I will share the logged errors.  They basically point back to line '86' which is where this code is.  I can run the application IIS locally and it runs just fine, but breaks when published.

Logged errors from **Azure Event Logs**

```
Source: IIS AspNetCore Module V2
Application '/LM/W3SVC/665542692/ROOT' with physical root 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\' failed to load coreclr. Exception message:
    CLR worker thread exited prematurely
    Process Id: 19728.
    File Version: 15.0.21196.9. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: c663adee8e64ba5d379fa0edfb8201984a7df7d0

Source: IIS AspNetCore Module V2
Application '/LM/W3SVC/665542692/ROOT' with physical root 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\' hit unexpected managed exception, exception code = '0xe0434352'. First 30KB characters of captured stdout and stderr logs:
    crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[6]
          Application startup exception
          System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: D:\home\site\wwwroot\Files\
             at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
             at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root)
             at BlazorApp1.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in F:\Documents\GitHub\WahlenApp\BlazorApp1\Startup.cs:line 86
             at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
             at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
             at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: D:\home\site\wwwroot\Files\
       at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root)
       at BlazorApp1.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in F:\Documents\GitHub\WahlenApp\BlazorApp1\Startup.cs:line 86
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
       at BlazorApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in F:\Documents\GitHub\WahlenApp\BlazorApp1\Program.cs:line 18
    
    Process Id: 19728.
    File Version: 15.0.21196.9. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: c663adee8e64ba5d379fa0edfb8201984a7df7d0

Source: .NET runtime
Application: w3wp.exe
CoreCLR Version: 5.0.921.35908
.NET Version: 5.0.9
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: D:\home\site\wwwroot\Files\
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root)
   at BlazorApp1.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in F:\Documents\GitHub\WahlenApp\BlazorApp1\Startup.cs:line 86
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at BlazorApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in F:\Documents\GitHub\WahlenApp\BlazorApp1\Program.cs:line 18

Source: .NET Runtime
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics
EventId: 6

Application startup exception

Exception: 
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: D:\home\site\wwwroot\Files\
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root)
   at BlazorApp1.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in F:\Documents\GitHub\WahlenApp\BlazorApp1\Startup.cs:line 86
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I have done a bunch of searching and find that I'm not the only one that has run into this problem in the past.  I tried many suggested 'solutions', but to no avail.

Comment: Did you install .NET5 hosting bundle on your target server?

Comment: I did that within configuration, general settings. '.net version' .net 5.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my issue.

In my .csproj file.
I have this line.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.10.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I downgraded to version 12.8.0 and it now works when published.  I would assume something in how this function needs to be coded has changed since the older version.